# Invoke throwing InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, delegates, invoke

I'm having a bit of an issue that I'm stumped on and I was hoping someone could shed some light on it. I have a `Form` called `form2` and I'm running some code to add some items to the `Listview(s)` of that form using a `MethodInvoker` so that the UI thread stays responsive while I do so.

Everything runs fine with it the first time around but then ***when I close that form (the one with the Listview on it) and run my code again*** I get a `InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created`.

So I looked into this and Googled it a bit more as well as looked on StackOverflow and I saw the issue was being caused by the form not having a handle created for it since it's being disposed when it's closed the first time.
So my solution was to have it force the form to set a handle for itself via `CreateControl()`. Even after using this, my form still isn't setting the handle when I inspect it in the break from the exception. It has `00x0000000` or something like that, and I'm still getting my `InvalidOperationException`. I have also tried to checked `.isDisposed()` and tried to use `CreateControl()` after that with no luck. Have any of you guys heard of this before? The other threads on SO have yield no solutions for me.

My Code:

```
            if (!form2.IsHandleCreated)
            {          
             form2.CreateControl();
            }


            form2.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
             //Do Stuff Here.
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since nobody responded to this I'll answer my own question in case anybody comes across this and it helps them. I actually ended up putting this outside the scope of my new thread that was created and creating the form in a button `click` event. I then checked to see if my form was `Disposed` or still open and created new instances of the Form based on that.

This is my code:

```
    var checkDMS = CheckIfNull(dealtxt.Text);
    if (checkDMS)
    {
        //If DMS Deal is valid -> If Form is Closed -> 
        if (form2.IsDisposed)
        {
            // If Form not open -> Create new instance 
            form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
            form2.SendToBack();
        }
        else
        {
            // If Form still open -> Close and make new instance.
            form2.Close();
            form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
            form2.SendToBack();
        }

        runDMSQueryFromNewThread(materialCheckBox1.Checked);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot Pull Deal From DMS.");
    }
```